# Can we create a anonymous block and run in AWS Redshift like in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Can we create a anonymous block and run in AWS Redshift like in Oracle PL/SQL ?  I was trying to execute the following block in Redshift and getting an error “SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "record"  Position: 14
Fyi:- I dont want to create a stored procedure /function.

```
declare
cur record;
begin
    for cur in select table_name from svv_tables t
    loop      
        execute 'select count(*) from '||cur.table_name ;
       commit;
    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

From Redshift's docs it seems they don't support `DO` at this moment.